# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I have the following function included on my website, solely used on the home page. However, when I go to another internal page that does not require the use of this function, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` in the console because the classes don't exist. Is there something I can add to this code to prevent the console errors?

```
$('.artist-kina').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#artists").offset().top - (
          $(window).width() < 450 ? 112 : 60
        )
    }, 500);
    $('.artists-home').fadeOut(function() {
        $('.kina-gallery').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: which means the element `#artists` does not exists

Comment: can you log the value of `$elem.length` before `if(isScrolledIntoView($elem)){` like `console.log($elem.length)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check how many element matched your selector.

```
$('.artist-kina').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($("#artists").length > 1) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#artists").offset().top - (
                $(window).width() < 450 ? 112 : 60
            )
        }, 500);
    }
    $('.artists-home').fadeOut(function() {
        $('.kina-gallery').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this but now it looks like the functions don't work on the home page where the functions are being used.

Comment: Can you show how did you include your internal page?

Comment: The internal pages (i.e. all pages except the home page) are just simple text or image links.

Comment: I get the same result. The function stops working on the home page.